# hql query for getting record for last 12 hours

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a table to record login activity. In my app dashboard, I want to show the last logins in a graph. Number of user logged in hourly interval. The query is to return result like this:

```
time                         count
-------                      --------
9.00.00 - 9.59.59            1
10.00.00 - 10.59.59          0
11.00.00 - 11.59.59          13
12.00.00 - 12.59.59          7
13.00.00 - 13.59.59          4
```

The entity`(LoginActivity)`has `dateLastUpdated` field, on which the query should work on. What will be the query to get expected result? A proper native workaround query will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select la from LoginActivity la where la.dateLastUpdated > :date");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -12);
Date date = cal.getTime();
query.setParameter("date", date);
List result = query.list();
```

Here's a shorter example

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select la from LoginActivity la where la.dateLastUpdated > :date");
query.setParameter("date", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 12*60*60*1000);
List result = query.list();
```

**EDIT**

Following Guillaume Polet's example (upvoted), it turns out there is a JPA way to do this (much better than having to use database vendor specific SQL functions). This code is working for me

```
    String query = "select hour(la.dateLastUpdated) as hour, count (la) from LoginActivity la " +
        "where la.dateLastUpdated > :date " +
        "group by hour(la.dateLastUpdated) " +
        "order by hour(la.dateLastUpdated)";

    List<Object[]> objects = getSession().createQuery(query).setParameter("date", date).list();

    for (Object[] o : objects) {
        Object hour = o[0];
        Object count = o[1];
        System.out.println(hour + ".00.00 - " + hour + ".59.59\t" + count);
    }
```

Comment: it'll give all the records in last 12 hours. But my expected result is the hourly count. How can it be same

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the question well enough. I think native SQL is the only option here then, will update my answer if I come up with a working example.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: it doesn't return the count 0 entries. how can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

Your query will need to rely on some hibernate specifics to handle the group by and the time interval manipulation.

Coul not test it but it should be something along those lines

```
 String query = "Select day (la.dateLastUpdated) as day, hour(la.dateLastUpdated) as hour, count (la)
 From LoginActivity la
 Where la.dateLastUpdated > :date
 Group by day, hour
 Order by day, hour";

 List <Object []> objects = em.createQuery (query, Object [].class).setParameter ("date", new Date (System.currentTimeInMillis ()-TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis (12))).getResultList ();
 for(Object [] o:objects) {
      Object hour = o[1];
      Object count = o [2];
      System.out.println (hour + ".00.00 - " + hour + "59.59\t" + count);
 }
```

Comment: hours with login count `0` aren't showed up. Can you suggest anything for that?

Comment: @fatCop You could check in the loop if any of the expected hours are missing and automatically flll in the possible gaps yourself.

Comment: yes, currently I'm doing the same. But can the query return the expected result set?

Comment: @fatCop in pure hql? it's unlikely. Maybe using some DB-specifics and a native query you could achieve that, but that's about as much effort as doing it in memory. The overhead of doing it in memory is minimal, so I would just stick to that approach